# Как исправить ошибку net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR в react при Post запросе

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, webpack, node-modules

Я пробовал использовать https но он выдавал ошибку BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js я её исправил при помощи config-overrides.js с кодом

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');
const TransformNodeEnvInlinePlugin = require('babel-plugin-transform-node-env-inline');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  // Find the rule for JavaScript files
  const jsRule = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.oneOf);
  if (jsRule) {
    // Add the plugin to use 'https' in your project
    jsRule.oneOf.forEach(rule => {
      if (rule.loader && rule.loader.includes('babel-loader')) {
        if (rule.options && rule.options.plugins) {
          // Add the missing plugin
          rule.options.plugins.push(TransformNodeEnvInlinePlugin);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  // Add the NodePolyfillPlugin
  config.plugins.push(new NodePolyfillPlugin());

  // Add the configuration to use 'https' in your project
  config.resolve.alias = {
    ...config.resolve.alias,
    https: 'https-browserify',
  };

  return config;
};
```

но это не исправило ошибку net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, вот мой код

```
import axios from "axios";
import api from "../Requests/axios/axios"
import FormData from "form-data";
import https from 'https'

export const login = async (username, password) => {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("username", username);
    formData.append("password", password);

    // Определяем конфигурацию запроса
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
            rejectUnauthorized: false,
        }),
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post("https://212.113.123.140:83/login/", formData, config);
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        // Обработка ошибок
        console.error("Error during login:", error);
        throw error; // Вы можете обработать ошибку здесь или передать ее вызывающему коду
    }
}
```

Comment: ваш вопрос имеет отношение только лишь к настройке сервера, который отдаёт ответы с `212.113.123.140:83`. есть ли там сертификат? правильно ли там настроен сервер?  вот с этими вопросами вы должны разобраться